# SQL Query Month Name Sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert this SQL View to sort the month names in order. 
Any help would be appreciated:

```
SELECT    DATENAME(Month, REQDATE) AS Month, COUNT(WO_NUM) AS Tickets
FROM      dbo.TASKS
WHERE     (REQDATE >= '6/1/13')
GROUP BY  DATENAME(Month, REQDATE)
```

It currently displays the months out of order..

Comment: do you want them sorted alphabetically or by calendar order?  January, February, March, etc. or April, August, December...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT    MAX(DATENAME(Month, REQDATE)) AS Month, COUNT(WO_NUM) AS Tickets
FROM      dbo.TASKS
WHERE     (REQDATE >= '6/1/13')
GROUP BY  DATEPART(Month, REQDATE)  
ORDER BY  DATEPART(Month, REQDATE) ASC
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/220be/4

Comment: I get an error when running this on SQL Server 2008. `Column "dbo.TASKS.REQDATE" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @user1854651 Last try. Try it now.

Comment: @AdamPorad Last try. Try it now.

Comment: [Please spell out `MONTH` instead of using lazy/ambiguous shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: I suspect the the intent would be better served by `DATENAME(Month, MAX(REQDATE))` rather than `MAX(DATENAME(Month, REQDATE))`.

Comment: @Allan You cannot go without the MAX for syntactic reason. Regarding mm vs Month - done.

Comment: I just moved the `max`. As written, I believe the query will return the alphabetic maximum, rather than the chronological maximum.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Shorthand or not is a matter of preference. For me it's the same.

Comment: @Allan Please test it. I am not sure what you're talking about. Think on it some more. All of them have the same MAX in that group, this is what I am using here.

Comment: @peter consider your audience, not just you. Did you read the link? Do you want to provide clear answers or ambiguous ones? Do you want to teach other people to code clearly or ambiguously? Do you really gain all that much by not having to type three whole characters?

Comment: Yes, I saw what you write there: "I feel like I'm taking this quiz every time I see code like the values on the left. Don't make me think; spell out what you mean. Please." -> The mm is not ambiguous OK? Cryptic - yes, agreed. But it means same as Month and only that. I get your point but I told you my opinion and as you see I updated my answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand "Discussio mater veritas est" I will remember that discussion with you btw, I think I will write Month from now on :) The mm is cryptic indeed and I hate cryptic (in other languages mostly). Just haven't thought about "mm vs Month" in SQL that much. Good luck.

Comment: @peter sure, just try `Y` vs `YEAR` and you'll quickly understand why I find them ambiguous - and even though you know that `MM` means month, it could also mean minute, microsecond, etc. And the point is about coding consistently, and showing newer users best practices (coding consistently and being as unambiguous as you can) - why type `YEAR` because you know `Y` is wrong, but type `MM` instead of `MONTH` because you know *in that case* the short form isn't wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This will display the results with the months listed in calendar order.

```
SELECT    DATENAME(Month, REQDATE) AS Month, COUNT(WO_NUM) AS Tickets
FROM      dbo.TASKS
WHERE     (REQDATE >= '6/1/13')
GROUP BY  DATENAME(Month, REQDATE), DATEPART(Month, REQDATE)
ORDER BY  DATEPART(Month, REQDATE) ASC
```

I added `DATEPART(Month, REQDATE)` to the GROUP BY clause, which shouldn't effect the grouping as the result for that DATEPART function will be the same for all dates in each group.

Comment: Sick! Thanks Adam.

Answer (score 0):

The TSQL function DatePart() should get you the month as an integer.  Try this:

```
SELECT    DATENAME(Month, REQDATE) AS Month, COUNT(WO_NUM) AS Tickets
FROM      dbo.TASKS
WHERE     (REQDATE >= '6/1/13')
ORDER BY DatePart(month, REQDATE)
GROUP BY  DatePart(Month, REQDATE), DateName(Month, REQDATE)
```

Comment: Column "dbo.TASKS.REQDATE" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Good point.  I changed the groupby to use DatePart instead of DateName.  Hmmm.  Maybe it should have both.   Let me change it again.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for the answer. Trick is to use AVG on the dates month.

```
SELECT    DATENAME(Month, REQDATE) AS Month, COUNT(WO_NUM) AS Tickets, AVG(DATEPART(mm, REQDATE)) AS MonthNum
FROM      dbo.TASKS
WHERE     (REQDATE >= '6/1/13')
GROUP BY  DATENAME(Month, REQDATE)  
ORDER BY  MonthNum ASC
```